# Quickly update django model objects from pandas dataframe

Tags: django-models, django-views, celery-task, django-3.0

I have a Django model that records transactions. I need to update only some of the fields (two) of some of the transactions.

In order to update, the user is asked to provide additional data and I use pandas to make calculations using this extra data.

I use the output from the pandas script to update the original model like this:

```
for i in df.tnsx_uuid:
    t = Transactions.objects.get(tnsx_uuid=i)
    t.start_bal = df.loc[df.tnsx_uuid==i].start_bal.values[0]
    t.end_bal = df.loc[df.tnsx_uuid==i].end_bal.values[0]
    t.save()
```

this is very slow. What is the best way to do this?

UPDATE:
after some more research, I found [bulk_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) and changed the code to:

```py
transactions = Transactions.objects.select_for_update()\
        .filter(tnsx_uuid__in=list(df.tnsx_uuid)).only('start_bal', 'end_bal')
for t in transactions:
    i = t.tnsx_uuid
    t.start_bal = df.loc[df.tnsx_uuid==i].start_bal.values[0]
    t.end_bal = df.loc[df.tnsx_uuid==i].end_bal.values[0]
Transactions.objects.bulk_update(transactions, ['start_bal', 'end_bal'])
```

this has approximately halved the time required.

How can I improve performance further?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the answer to this question and haven't found any authoritative, idiomatic solutions. So, here's what I've settled on for my own use:

```py
transaction = Transactions.objects.filter(tnsx_uuid__in=list(df.tnsx_uuid))
# Build a DataFrame of Django model instances
trans_df = pd.DataFrame([{'tnsx_uuid': t.tnsx_uuid, 'object': t} for t in transactions])
# Join the Django instances to the main DataFrame on the index
df = df.join(trans_df.set_index('tnsx_uuid'))

for obj, start_bal, end_bal in zip(df['object'], df['start_bal'], df['end_bal']):
    obj.start_bal = start_bal
    obj.end_bal = send_bal

Transactions.objects.bulk_update(df['object'], ['start_bal', 'end_bal'])
```

I don't know how `DataFrame.loc[]` is implemented but it *could* be slow if it needs to search the whole DataFrame for each use rather than just do a hash lookup. For that reason and to just simply things by doing a single iteration loop, I pulled all of the model instances into `df` and then used the [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/3465823) from a Stackoverflow answer on iterating over a DataFrames to loop over the zipped columns of interest.

I looked at the documentation for [select_for_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) in Django and it isn't apparent to me that it offers a performance improvement, but you may be using it to lock the transaction and make all of the changes atomically. Per the documentation, `bulk_update` should be faster than saving each object individually.

In my case, I'm only updating 3500 items. I did some timing of the various steps and came up with the following:

- 3.05 s to query and build the DataFrame
- 2.79 ms to join the instances to `df`
- 5.79 ms to run the `for` loop and update the instances
- 1.21 s to bulk_update the changes

So, I think you would need to profile your code to see what is actually taking time, but it is likely a Django issue rather than a Pandas issue.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of face the same issue (almost same quantity of records 3500~), and I will like to add:

- bulk_update seems to be a lot worse in performance than a
  bulk_create, in my case deleting objects was allowed, so
  instead of bulk_updating, I delete all objects, and then recreate them.
- I used the same approach as you (thanks for the idea), but with some modifications:

a) I create the dataframe from the query itself:

```
all_objects_values = all_objects.values('id', 'date', 'amount')
self.df_values = pd.DataFrame.from_records(all_objects_values )
```

b) Then I create the column of objects without iterating (I make sure these are ordered):

```
self.df_values['object'] = list(all_objects)
```

c) For updating object values (after operations made in my dataframe), I iterate rows(not sure about performance difference):

```
 for index, row in self.df_values.iterrows():
     row['object'].amount= row['amount']
```

d) At the end, I re-create all objects:

```
MyModel.objects.bulk_create(self.df_values['object'].tolist())
```

Conclusion:

- In my case, the most time consuming was the bulk update, so re-creating objects solved it for me (from 19 seconds with bulk_update to 10 seconds with delete + bulk_create)
- In your case, using my approach may improve the time for all other operations.